# Estimating the growth of the Taylor coefficients given the growth of the function at the boundary

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, harmonic-analysis, taylor-series

Let $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ be a Taylor series that converges for $|z|<1$ and satisfies
$$
|f(z)|\le \frac{1}{(1-|z|)^{k}}
$$
for some fixed $k>0$.

**Question:** What can I deduce about the growth of the Taylor coefficients $a_n$?

**Partial result:** By judiciously selecting the location of the contour in the formula $a_n=\oint z^{-n}f(z)\tfrac{dz}{2\pi i z}$, namely, by performing the integration over the contour $|z|=\tfrac{n}{n+k}$ [which is the minimum of $|z|^{-n}(1-|z|)^{-k}$], I can get the "trivial bound" $|a_n|< c\cdot n^k$.

But I suspect that this is not sharp.
In particular, the growth of the Taylor coefficients of $(1-z)^{-k}$ is only $n^{k-1}$. Not $n^k$.

**More precise formulation of the question:**
 What is the optimal $k'>0$ such that
$$
|f(z)|\le \frac{1}{(1-|z|)^{k}}\quad\Rightarrow\quad |a_n|< c\cdot n^{k'}
$$
for all $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$.

From the above arguments, I know that $k-1\le k'\le k$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling. Yes, I'm also interested in various variants of this question, such as $|f(z)|\le 1$, and $|f(z)|\le -\log(1-|z|)$.

Comment: For example $f(z)=\sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{e^{in \log n}}{\sqrt n \log^2n}z^n$ is continuous hence bounded in the closed unit disc but its coefficients are only $o(1/\sqrt n)$ and not $o(n^{-1/2-\epsilon})$ and similar examples should be manufactured for $k >0$

Comment: @Conrad: This is interesting. Can you please explain why $f$ is continuous?

Comment: actually I may be wrong as there is a result of Pommerenke (?) proved on page 71 (Thm 3.3) in Hayman Multivalent Functions (2nd edition) that gives the required estimate $|a_n| \le C_pn^{-k-1}$ for $k >1/2$ and mean $p$-multivalent functions satisfying the estimate in the OP, while for $0 \le k<1/2$ one can get only $o(n^{-1/2})$ but not better; of course this doesn't prove the result in general for $k >1/2$ as one has to deal with functions that may be $\infty$ valent, but it provides counterxamples for $0 \le k <1/2$

Comment: @Christian By partial summation using that $s_N(t)=\sum_{n=2}^N e^{in \log n}e^{int}$ are $O(\sqrt N)$ uniformly in $t$, the estimate coming from the standard Van der Corput second derivative test applied to $f(x)=(x \log x+xt)/(2\pi)$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The optimal exponent is $k$. Such examples are given by sparse power series. This is actually trivial in the case $k=0$ (which was not included in the OP). Then we can simply take $f(z)=\sum j^{-2} z^{N(j)}$, say. This is obviously bounded, and the coefficients $a_n$ will not satisfy $|a_n|\lesssim n^{-\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$ if $N(j)$ increases fast enough.

For positive $k$, we can similarly consider something like
$$
f(z)=\sum n^{-2} \left(n^n\right)^k z^{n^n} .
$$
Using calculus to find the maximum, we see that
$$
x^k(1-\delta)^x \le C\delta^{-k} .
$$
Thus $f$ satisfies the desired bound, but the coefficients do not satisfy $|a_n|\lesssim n^{k-\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: that's why one needs some conditions on $f$ to get non-trivial results (eg $p$ valence for some finite $p$ where area considerations come into effect so give better bounds)

Comment: Thank you Christian, that's great [though not the answer I wanted :-)]. I wonder what would happen if I were to add the further condition that the $a_n$ form a decreasing sequence...

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, I meant $|a_n|$ decreasing. But don't worry about that. This was just a thought prompted by Conrad's statement that "one needs some condition on $f$ to get non trivial results".